How to use long table in latex on overleaf my table is not going on to second page, Its only on one page and truncating
\begin{document}    
\begin{table}[H] 
\caption{Comparative Analysis of most prominent literature work\label{tab1}}
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=5\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=10\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=10\hsize}X}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{xzyy}
\toprule
\textbf{Source} & \textbf{Techniques}   & \textbf{Strength} & \textbf{Weakness}\\
\midrule
Madhu Oruganti 2024 \cite{cite26}    & Curvelet Transform (CLT) and CNN      & Improved     feature similarity, enhanced discriminative power. & Capturing dynamic age-related changes over time.\\  

Yan, Chunman 2024 \cite{cite25}  &  Multi-scale fusion with CNN  & Global and local features & Complex and high computational cost due.\\

Nermeen Nader 2024 \cite{cite24}  & Fusion of Color-Texture and Color Features & Remove Illumination issue. & High computational complexity, extensive preprocessing and normalization steps.\\

Li, Houjie 2024 \cite{cite23} &  Online Re-weighting Relation Network (OR2Net) &  Multi-scale features, Addresses data imbalance & Complex, require significant computational resources and tuning.\\

Peng, Jia Luo 2023 \cite{cite22} & Multi-task Learning with Attention Module and Fairness-aware Contrastive Loss. & Mitigates racial bias, improves accuracy. & High Computation\\

Xu, Min 2023 \cite{cite21}  & Angular Scaling Calibration (ASC) & Implementation, compatibile & Not for all noise. \\

Khammari, M. 2023 \cite{cite20} & MSRCP and GRF & MSRCP and GRF & High computational complexity, preprocssing time. \\

Mahpod, Shahar, 2023 \cite{cite19} &  Multiview hybrid symmetric and asymmetric distance learning network. & Effectively learns. & high computational resources and large amounts of labeled data.\\

Wang, X 2023 \cite{cite18} & Incremental Update Kinship Identification (INK) & Balances privacy and accuracy, adaptable to heterogeneous datasets. & Complex implementation. \\

Pernuš, M 2023 \cite{cite17} & Generative Adversarial Network (GAN) & High resemblance to real parents' children, fine-grained control over synthesis, ability to generate multiple images. & Complexity in training GANs and potential issues with mode collapse.\\

Jiang, Wei 2022 \cite{cite16} & Sample correlation-based genomic relationship matrix (scGRM), UKin & Reduces bias and root mean square error in kinship coefficient estimation. & Complex\\

Liu, Fan 2022 \cite{cite15} & Age-Invariant Adversarial Feature Learning (AIAF) with Identity Feature Weighted module (IFW). & Reduces the impact of age differences. & High implementation complexity and resource requirement.\\

Wu, Xiaoting 2022 \cite{cite14} & Unified Adaptive Adversarial Multimodal Learning (UAAML) & Integrates multiple modalities for better performance. & Complex to implement and train.\\

Almuashi, Mohammed 2022 \cite{cite13} & SCNN-FBOB & Removes weak local blocks to enhance accuracy; utilizes only the most informative regions. & Computationally intensive.\\

Dong, Guan-Nan 2021  \cite{cite10} & Cross-Generation Feature Interaction Learning (CFIL) & Integrates similarity learning and feature extraction. & Complex\\

Yan, Haibin 2021 \cite{cite9} & Deep Relational Network & Local region focus enhances feature extraction. & Increased complexity and computational requirements.\\

Wu, Huishan 2021 \cite{cite11} & Component-based metric learning (CML) and SIFT descriptors. & No need for manual face alignment, improved verification accuracy. & Potentially complex implementation and computationally intensive.\\

Bessaoudi, Mohcene 2021 \cite{cite12} & Tensor Cross-view Quadratic Discriminant Analysis (TCQDA). & Improved accuracy through multi-view representation learning. & Potential complexity in implementation and computational cost.\\

Dahan, Eran 2020 \cite{cite6} & Unified Multi-Task Learning Scheme & Small training sets, prevents overfitting through novel fusion of embeddings, resolves dataset imbalance with adaptive sampling. & Complexity in model design and potential computational overhead.\\

Zhang, Lei 2020 \cite{cite5} & Family ID-based Adversarial Convolutional Network (AdvKin) & Enhanced kinship recognition by incorporating family ID information and adversarial mechanisms. & Complexity in model training due to multiple loss functions and network layers.\\

Dornaika, Fadi 2020 \cite{cite4} & Kinship-oriented Discriminant Data Projection with Multi-Level Fusion & Efficient feature selection. & Computationally intensive. Complexity in merging strategies.\\

Charpentier, Marie 2020 \cite{cite7} & Deep learning for face recognition. & Effective in identifying kinship signals. & Not suitable for all environmental factors influencing resemblance.\\

Brumpton, Ben 2020 \cite{cite8} & Within-family Mendelian randomization. & Reduces biases from familial effects. & Requires large family-based datasets for accurate analysis\\

Moujahid, Abdelmalik 2019 \cite{cite3} & Pyramid Multi-level (PML) Representation with Covariance Descriptor & Explicitly encodes scales and face parts, integrates various texture and color features. & Computationally complex due to covariance calculations across multiple blocks and scales.\\


\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\unskip
\end{document}



Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

BTW: Your question seems not to be [tag:latex3] related and not [tag:overleaf] specific. So please don't use such tags. It is a question about [tag:tables] and about [tag:page-breaking], so this tags do make sense. And I've also added [tag:longtable] to help you finding similar questions.

The question is also similar to: Tabularx: Break long tables over several pages

(unrelated to your question, but centred cells make the table look messy and hard to read because the eye has trouble following the line)

Some suggestions, in no particular order.

Whatever else you do, don't use a table environment, since the contents of table environments cannot be broken across pages. Likewise, you can't use a tabularx environment since its contents can't be broken across pages either.

I suggest you employ an xltabular environment instead, which combines the capabilities of the longtable (span two or more pages) and tabularx (take a target width, e.g., \textwidth) environments. Observe that an xltabular environment is not a "float" (in the LaTeX-specific sense of the term).

I also wouldn't center-set the cell contents; suppressing full justification (while still allowing hyphenation) would seem to be preferable.

Do please make an effort to avoid bad line breaks in non-English language words -- such as the given names "Xiaoting" and "Huishan".


The following screenshot shows the first page of the 3-page table that results from implementing these suggestions. (The result also depends on auxiliary assumptions -- such as which document class is in use, or how wide and tall the page is -- that I had to make in order to make the document minimally compilable.)

\documentclass{article} % of some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize}X}

\hyphenation{xiao-ting hui-shan} % must avoid "xiaot-ing" and "huis-han"

\begin{document}


\begingroup % localize scope of next instruction
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} 

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} L{0.7} *{3}{L{1.1}} @{}}
%% Note: 0.7 + 3*1.1 = 4 = # of X-type columns
\caption{Comparative Analysis of most prominent literature work}\label{tab1}\\


%%% headers and footers

\toprule
Source & Techniques & Strength & Weakness \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued} \\[1ex]
\toprule
Source & Techniques & Strength & Weakness \\
\midrule
\endhead


\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\small(continued on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot


%%% body of table

Madhu Oruganti 2024 \cite{cite26} & Curvelet Transform (CLT) and CNN & Improved feature similarity, enhanced discriminative power. & Capturing dynamic age-related changes over time.\\

Yan, Chunman 2024 \cite{cite25} & Multi-scale fusion with CNN & Global and local features & Complex and high computational cost due.\\

Nermeen Nader 2024 \cite{cite24} & Fusion of Color-Texture and Color Features & Remove Illumination issue. & High computational complexity, extensive preprocessing and normalization steps.\\

Li, Houjie 2024 \cite{cite23} & Online Re-weighting Relation Network (OR2Net) & Multi-scale features, Addresses data imbalance & Complex, require significant computational resources and tuning.\\

Peng, Jia Luo 2023 \cite{cite22} & Multi-task Learning with Attention Module and Fairness-aware Contrastive Loss. & Mitigates racial bias, improves accuracy. & High Computation\\

Xu, Min 2023 \cite{cite21} & Angular Scaling Calibration (ASC) & Implementation, compatibile & Not for all noise. \\

Khammari, M. 2023 \cite{cite20} & MSRCP and GRF & MSRCP and GRF & High computational complexity, preprocssing time. \\

Mahpod, Shahar, 2023 \cite{cite19} & Multiview hybrid symmetric and asymmetric distance learning network. & Effectively learns. & high computational resources and large amounts of labeled data.\\

Wang, X 2023 \cite{cite18} & Incremental Update Kinship Identification (INK) & Balances privacy and accuracy, adaptable to heterogeneous datasets. & Complex implementation. \\

Pernuš, M 2023 \cite{cite17} & Generative Adversarial Network (GAN) & High resemblance to real parents' children, fine-grained control over synthesis, ability to generate multiple images. & Complexity in training GANs and potential issues with mode collapse.\\

Jiang, Wei 2022 \cite{cite16} & Sample correlation-based genomic relationship matrix (scGRM), UKin & Reduces bias and root mean square error in kinship coefficient estimation. & Complex\\

Liu, Fan 2022 \cite{cite15} & Age-Invariant Adversarial Feature Learning (AIAF) with Identity Feature Weighted module (IFW). & Reduces the impact of age differences. & High implementation complexity and resource requirement.\\

Wu, Xiaoting 2022 \cite{cite14} & Unified Adaptive Adversarial Multimodal Learning (UAAML) & Integrates multiple modalities for better performance. & Complex to implement and train.\\

Almuashi, Mohammed 2022 \cite{cite13} & SCNN-FBOB & Removes weak local blocks to enhance accuracy; utilizes only the most informative regions. & Computationally intensive.\\

Dong, Guan-Nan 2021 \cite{cite10} & Cross-Generation Feature Interaction Learning (CFIL) & Integrates similarity learning and feature extraction. & Complex\\

Yan, Haibin 2021 \cite{cite9} & Deep Relational Network & Local region focus enhances feature extraction. & Increased complexity and computational requirements.\\

Wu, Huishan 2021 \cite{cite11} & Component-based metric learning (CML) and SIFT descriptors. & No need for manual face alignment, improved verification accuracy. & Potentially complex implementation and computationally intensive.\\

Bessaoudi, Mohcene 2021 \cite{cite12} & Tensor Cross-view Quadratic Discriminant Analysis (TCQDA). & Improved accuracy through multi-view representation learning. & Potential complexity in implementation and computational cost.\\

Dahan, Eran 2020 \cite{cite6} & Unified Multi-Task Learning Scheme & Small training sets, prevents overfitting through novel fusion of embeddings, resolves dataset imbalance with adaptive sampling. & Complexity in model design and potential computational overhead.\\

Zhang, Lei 2020 \cite{cite5} & Family ID-based Adversarial Convolutional Network (AdvKin) & Enhanced kinship recognition by incorporating family ID information and adversarial mechanisms. & Complexity in model training due to multiple loss functions and network layers.\\

Dornaika, Fadi 2020 \cite{cite4} & Kinship-oriented Discriminant Data Projection with Multi-Level Fusion & Efficient feature selection. & Computationally intensive. Complexity in merging strategies.\\

Charpentier, Marie 2020 \cite{cite7} & Deep learning for face recognition. & Effective in identifying kinship signals. & Not suitable for all environmental factors influencing resemblance.\\

Brumpton, Ben 2020 \cite{cite8} & Within-family Mendelian randomization. & Reduces biases from familial effects. & Requires large family-based datasets for accurate analysis\\

Moujahid, Abdelmalik 2019 \cite{cite3} & Pyramid Multi-level (PML) Representation with Covariance Descriptor & Explicitly encodes scales and face parts, integrates various texture and color features. & Computationally complex due to covariance calculations across multiple blocks and scales.\\

\end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\end{document} 


An alternative way, based on use of the tabularray package, \small font size for better filling texts in cells, in tables and slightly reduced int3erlines spaces:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Comparative Analysis of most prominent literature work},
  label = {tab1},
                ]{colsep  = 3pt,
                  colspec = {@{} X[0.7,l] *{3}{X[1.1, cmd=\RaggedRight]} @{}},
                  cells  = {font=\small\linespread{0.92}\selectfont},
                  rowhead = 1}
    \toprule
Source & Techniques & Strength & Weakness \\
    \midrule
Madhu Oruganti 2024 \cite{cite26} 
    & Curvelet Transform (CLT) and CNN 
        & Improved feature similarity, enhanced discriminative power. 
            & Capturing dynamic age-related changes over time.\\

Yan, Chunman 2024 \cite{cite25} 
    & Multi-scale fusion with CNN 
        & Global and local features 
            & Complex and high computational cost due.\\

Nermeen Nader 2024 \cite{cite24} 
    & Fusion of Color-Texture and Color Features 
        & Remove Illumination issue. 
            & High computational complexity, extensive preprocessing and normalization steps.\\

Li, Houjie 2024 \cite{cite23} 
    & Online Re-weighting Relation Network (OR2Net) 
        & Multi-scale features, Addresses data imbalance 
            & Complex, require significant computational resources and tuning.\\

Peng, Jia Luo 2023 \cite{cite22} 
    & Multi-task Learning with Attention Module and Fairness-aware Contrastive Loss. 
        & Mitigates racial bias, improves accuracy. 
            & High Computation  \\

Xu, Min 2023 \cite{cite21} 
    & Angular Scaling Calibration (ASC) 
        & Implementation, compatibile 
            & Not for all noise. \\

Khammari, M. 2023 \cite{cite20} & MSRCP and GRF & MSRCP and GRF & High computational complexity, preprocssing time. \\

Mahpod, Shahar, 2023 \cite{cite19} 
    & Multiview hybrid symmetric and asymmetric distance learning network. 
        & Effectively learns. 
            & high computational resources and large amounts of labeled data.\\

Wang, X 2023 \cite{cite18} 
    & Incremental Update Kinship Identification (INK) 
        & Balances privacy and accuracy, adaptable to heterogeneous datasets. 
            & Complex implementation. \\

Pernuš, M 2023 \cite{cite17} 
    & Generative Adversarial Network (GAN)  
        & High resemblance to real parents' children, fine-grained control over synthesis, ability to generate multiple images. 
            & Complexity in training GANs and potential issues with mode collapse.\\

Jiang, Wei 2022 \cite{cite16} 
    & Sample correlation-based genomic relationship matrix (scGRM), UKin & Reduces bias and root mean square error in kinship coefficient estimation. 
        & Complex\\

Liu, Fan 2022 \cite{cite15} 
    & Age-Invariant Adversarial Feature Learning (AIAF) with Identity Feature Weighted module (IFW). 
        & Reduces the impact of age differences. 
            & High implementation complexity and resource requirement.\\

Wu, Xiaoting 2022 \cite{cite14} 
    & Unified Adaptive Adversarial Multimodal Learning (UAAML) 
        & Integrates multiple modalities for better performance. 
            & Complex to implement and train.\\

Almuashi, Mohammed 2022 \cite{cite13} 
    & SCNN-FBOB 
        & Removes weak local blocks to enhance accuracy; utilizes only the most informative regions. 
            & Computationally intensive.\\

Dong, Guan-Nan 2021 \cite{cite10} 
    & Cross-Generation Feature Interaction Learning (CFIL) 
        & Integrates similarity learning and feature extraction. 
            & Complex\\

Yan, Haibin 2021 \cite{cite9} 
    & Deep Relational Network 
        & Local region focus enhances feature extraction. 
            & Increased complexity and computational requirements.\\

Wu, Huishan 2021 \cite{cite11} 
    & Component-based metric learning (CML) and SIFT descriptors. 
        & No need for manual face alignment, improved verification accuracy. 
            & Potentially complex implementation and computationally intensive.\\

Bessaoudi, Mohcene 2021 \cite{cite12} 
    & Tensor Cross-view Quadratic Discriminant Analysis (TCQDA). & Improved accuracy through multi-view representation learning. 
        & Potential complexity in implementation and computational cost.\\

Dahan, Eran 2020 \cite{cite6} 
    & Unified Multi-Task Learning Scheme 
        & Small training sets, prevents overfitting through novel fusion of embeddings, resolves dataset imbalance with adaptive sampling. 
            & Complexity in model design and potential computational overhead.\\

Zhang, Lei 2020 \cite{cite5} 
    & Family ID-based Adversarial Convolutional Network (AdvKin) 
        & Enhanced kinship recognition by incorporating family ID information and adversarial mechanisms. 
            & Complexity in model training due to multiple loss functions and network layers.\\

Dornaika, Fadi 2020 \cite{cite4} 
    & Kinship-oriented Discriminant Data Projection with Multi-Level Fusion 
        & Efficient feature selection. 
            & Computationally intensive. Complexity in merging strategies.\\

Charpentier, Marie 2020 \cite{cite7} 
    & Deep learning for face recognition. 
        & Effective in identifying kinship signals. 
            & Not suitable for all environmental factors influencing resemblance.\\

Brumpton, Ben 2020 \cite{cite8} 
    & Within-family Mendelian randomization. 
        & Reduces biases from familial effects. 
            & Requires large family-based datasets for accurate analysis\\

Moujahid, Abdelmalik 2019 \cite{cite3} 
    & Pyramid Multi-level (PML) Representation with Covariance Descriptor 
        & Explicitly encodes scales and face parts, integrates various texture and color features. 
            & Computationally complex due to covariance calculations across multiple blocks and scales.\\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document} 


